# Is there a way to copy an object from a bucket to the Revit Design Automation local path?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I have created a bucket like following (Python):

`payload = {'bucketKey' : bucketname,'policyKey' : 'transient'}`

`resp = requests.post(Forge_BASE_URL+'/oss/v2/buckets', headers={'Authorization': config.token,'Content-Type':'application/json'},json=payload)`

And then uploaded a file to the bucket created:

`url = 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/'+bucketname+'/objects/'+encodedfilename`

`resp = requests.put(url, headers={'Authorization': config.token,'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream','Content-Length' : str(filesize)},data= open(modelfilePath + filename, 'rb'))`

How can I download the object from the bucket to the local path of the Revit Design Automation engine?
The local path of the Revit Design Automation engine looks like `T:\Aces\Jobs\job_id` that is used in C# codes.

Either `curl` command or Python codes are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually the responsibility of the Design Automation service to download all the inputs from provided (readable) URLs, run your activity in a secured, sandboxed environment, and then upload all the outputs to provided (writable) URLs.

If your input file is in a Forge Data Management bucket, you could get a temporary [signed URL](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-signed-POST/) for it, and use that as the URL for the activity input. You can also create *writable* signed URLs that the Design Automation activity can then upload the results to. See this [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/beginners-guide-design-automation-visual-studio-code) for more details.